# How can I restrict access to my files

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering how I **could restrict access to my folder called "objects"** which contains the JavaScript files, CSS files, etc, but let the index.html in the root directory use them. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rules in your objects directory,

```
Options -Indexes
<Files ~ "\.(js|css)">
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try it in a second.